# multi resoluation waveler PID (MRPID)

Tags: matlab

HI i have pid  code in Matlab. I want to inset multi resolution wavelet to enhancement the result of PID

```
clear all
clc

%%%%%%%%%%% PID controller %%%%%%%%%%%

    e(k)=r(k)-y(k);
    sum=sum+e(k)*0.1265;
    pe=e(k);
    kierr=ki*sum;
    kperr=kp*pe;
    dif=-dif-(e(k)/0.1265);
    kderr=kd*dif;
    u(k)=kperr+ kierr+kderr;

uu=ku*u(k);

       stepinfo(uu)

%%%%%%%%%%% system input limited between 0  and  1 %%%%%%%%%%%

    if (uu > 1)
        uu =1;
    elseif (uu < 0)
        uu=0;
    end
    x(k)=uu;
```

Comment: How can wavelets help with a PID controller?  That's mixing apples and oranges together.

Comment: i have papers applied this mixing input to wavelet is error .

Comment: error is feedback form controller